# selecting id of the row in the event of the link button inside the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have populate the data in gridview.In gridview I have one link button when click it will make one panel visible.Now I want to keep the id of that selected row in session and use that in panel.I also know how to find out the id of gridview but I am not being able to generate event of gridview when the link button of that specific row is selected.

```
 private void Bindgrid()
    {

        if (Session["CartId"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int introws = 0;
            //string mandir_id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            string cmdstr = "select p.id,p.name,p.photo_id,p.price,m.name from puja p,mandir m,shoppingcart s where s.session_id='" + Session["CartId"] + "' and p.with_mandir=m.id and p.id=s.with_puja";
            //sQLcONN.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, sQLcONN);
            MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            sQLcONN.Close();
        }
        else { }

    }

protected void Linkedit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        pnl1.Visible = true;

    }
```

And this is the button event inside the panel where I actually need to get that Id.

```
 protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       string  price = Session["price"].ToString();

        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        string url = string.Format("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s={0}{1}=X", ddlFrom.SelectedValue.ToUpper(), ddlTo.SelectedValue.ToUpper());
        string response = web.DownloadString(url);
        string[] values = Regex.Split(response, ",");
        decimal rate = System.Convert.ToDecimal(values[1]);
        decimal amount = System.Convert.ToDecimal(price);
        rate = rate * amount;
        //string  result = System.Convert.ToString(rate);
        //result = rate;
        //rate = System.Convert.ToDecimal(lblResult.Text);
        lblResult.Text = rate.ToString();
    }
```

Please help me to solve this....

Comment: you can use rowcommand event for this,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this..

```
   protected void Linkedit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          LinkButton  lnkedit  = sender as LinkButton;
          GridViewRow gvrow = lnkedit.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
          int index = gvrow.RowIndex;  
          pnl1.Visible = true;

        }
```

gvrow  is the gridview current row you can do what ever you want...

Comment: here index value is always coming as zero.

Comment: May be u are clicking on the 1st Row link in the gridview that's y? index is coming as "0". Please click on the other row link button then you can get the rowindex...I have tested the code it was working from my end....

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Code:**

```
 protected void Linkedit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           LinkButton lnk_Button = (LinkButton)sender;
           GridViewRow id = (GridViewRow)lnk_Button.NamingContainer;
           Session["id"] = (string)gvrow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();//here you get first coloumn value
           pnl1.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: Nop id is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

In GridView store your id like following:-

```
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource4">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
  ImageUrl="~/Images/img.gif"   OnClick="imgbtn_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>'/>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

On `imgbtn_Click` get id and store in `Session`:-

```
 protected void imgbtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
            Session["Id"] = Convert.ToInt32((sender as ImageButton).CommandArgument);
            // show panel here
 }
```

In panel if you have `button` do the following:-

```
 <asp:Button ID="imgbtnSave" CausesValidation="False" runat="server" Text="yourText" OnClick="imgbtnSave_Click"/>

  protected void imgbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {

            int id =  Convert.ToInt32(Session["Id"]); 
            // do stuff with your id    
  }
```